# CS-Script in C#

Tags: c#

How do i pause execution for my CS-Script, How to wait main calling thread.

i have a loop. but second iteration started without completion of the first iteration. 
and second csscript executed.

```
foreach (var website in siteList)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = Common.GetWebSearchURL(website.ToUpper());
                string webFile = Common.GetWebSearchURL(website.ToUpper() + "_SCRIPT");
                CSScript.Evaluator.ReferenceAssembliesFromCode(webFile, true);
                ICommon script = CSScript.Evaluator.LoadFile<ICommon>(webFile);  
                script.Run(ref pnlBroswer, website, url);

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { } 
        }
```

Comment: Is the script doing asynchronous rather than synchronous work?

Answer (score 0):

You could also have the script leave some evidence that it completed. It could output a value to a text file, or just create a file, whatever. You call the script, then check for that indicator until you find it (or decide to give up), then continue.

```
bool CheckFile() { return someFileContainsValue }

try
{
    bool completed = false;
    executeScript(); // will update a text file when complete
    while(!completed)
    {
        completed = CheckFile();
    }
}
```

Obviously an async version would be cleaner, but the principle is the same.